# Http authentication from angular to DRF-simple JWT

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, jwt

Im trying to authenticate to a Django backend using Drf-simple-jwt from an angular front.
First of all, everything works great in Postman.
But I cannot get past HTTP 401 error when using the browser (Safari, Chrome).

I have set up Cord-Headers in Django:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:4200',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'backOffice.apps.BackofficeConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Here's the login call from angular :

```
login(user: Users) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.BASE_URL + 'api/token/', user)
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('login error: ', err);
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );

  }
```

And how I call it:

```
authenticate() {
    this.api.login(this.user).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("access", data.access);
        localStorage.setItem("refresh", data.refresh);
        this.router.navigate(['/accueil']);
      });

  }
```

Here's a view im trying to access:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
```

Im using [auth0/angular-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) to automatically append the Authorization header to each request.

I have no issues in Postman, all endpoints work fine.
But in the browser, all I get is HTTP 401.
Ive hardcoded a valid, just emitted access_token, in the headers to no avail.
I can see the `Authorization: Bearer <Token>` in the request, with a valid token, but still am Unauthorized.

From what I gathered it could be a cors issue, but I've set up cors header.

I would greatly appreciate any insight.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it is a CORS error, then there should be an accompanying error in the console. I do know that recently there was a CORS scheme rule update that now forbids http to https requests and I see that you are running localhost on http. Check to see what your backend is running on.

Comment: is you BE on https?

Comment: it is not, its on localhost:8000